# Problem with MERGE INTO in Bigquery using DBT

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dbt

I have generated code from DBT, which looks like this below

```sql
 merge into `dest_dataset` as DBT_INTERNAL_DEST
        using (

SELECT
  S.DATE,
  S.SHIFT,
  S.SHIFT_FROM,
  S.SHIFT_TO,
  S.WORKER,
  S.LOGIN,
  S.JOB,
  W.SHIFT_NAME,
  S.NOTE,
  W.AGENCY,
  UPPER(S.AGENCY) AS AGENCY_SHORT,
  S.WORKER_SURNAME,
  S.WORKER_NAME,
  S.HOUR_WORK_SHIFTS,
  W.ORGANIZATION_UNIT,
  W.TIME_IN,
  W.TIME_OUT,
  W.WORKED,
  W.BREAKS,
  CASE
    WHEN S.SHIFT_FROM = CAST('6:30:00' AS TIME)
         OR S.SHIFT_FROM = CAST('6:00:00' AS TIME) THEN 'day'
    WHEN S.SHIFT_FROM = CAST('18:30:00' AS TIME)
         OR S.SHIFT_FROM = CAST('18:00:00' AS TIME) THEN 'night'
  END AS SHIFT_TERM
FROM
  `shifts` AS S
LEFT OUTER JOIN `workers` AS W ON S.WORKER_NAME = W.NAME
  AND S.WORKER_SURNAME = W.SURNAME
  AND S.DATE = W.DATE
        ) as DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE
        on (
                    DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.DATE = DBT_INTERNAL_DEST.DATE
                ) and (
                    DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.WORKER = DBT_INTERNAL_DEST.WORKER
                )

    
    when matched then update set
        `DATE` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`DATE`,`SHIFT` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`SHIFT`,`SHIFT_FROM` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`SHIFT_FROM`,`SHIFT_TO` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`SHIFT_TO`,`WORKER` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`WORKER`,`LOGIN` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`LOGIN`,`JOB` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`JOB`,`SHIFT_NAME` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`SHIFT_NAME`,`NOTE` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`NOTE`,`AGENCY` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`AGENCY`,`AGENCY_SHORT` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`AGENCY_SHORT`,`WORKER_SURNAME` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`WORKER_SURNAME`,`WORKER_NAME` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`WORKER_NAME`,`HOUR_WORK_SHIFTS` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`HOUR_WORK_SHIFTS`,`ORGANIZATION_UNIT` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`ORGANIZATION_UNIT`,`TIME_IN` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`TIME_IN`,`TIME_OUT` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`TIME_OUT`,`WORKED` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`WORKED`,`BREAKS` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`BREAKS`,`SHIFT_TERM` = DBT_INTERNAL_SOURCE.`SHIFT_TERM`
    

    when not matched then insert
        (`DATE`, `SHIFT`, `SHIFT_FROM`, `SHIFT_TO`, `WORKER`, `LOGIN`, `JOB`, `SHIFT_NAME`, `NOTE`, `AGENCY`, `AGENCY_SHORT`, `WORKER_SURNAME`, `WORKER_NAME`, `HOUR_WORK_SHIFTS`, `ORGANIZATION_UNIT`, `TIME_IN`, `TIME_OUT`, `WORKED`, `BREAKS`, `SHIFT_TERM`)
    values
        (`DATE`, `SHIFT`, `SHIFT_FROM`, `SHIFT_TO`, `WORKER`, `LOGIN`, `JOB`, `SHIFT_NAME`, `NOTE`, `AGENCY`, `AGENCY_SHORT`, `WORKER_SURNAME`, `WORKER_NAME`, `HOUR_WORK_SHIFTS`, `ORGANIZATION_UNIT`, `TIME_IN`, `TIME_OUT`, `WORKED`, `BREAKS`, `SHIFT_TERM`)
```

, with the config set as:

```
{{ config(
    materialized='incremental',
    unique_key=['DATE', 'WORKER']
) }}
```

When I am running this code in DBT or BQ, I am receiving error:

> UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row

I checked and I do not have any duplicates in the source dataset (workers) when I am running query:

```sql
SELECT DATE, WORKER, COUNT(*)
FROM workers
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I am not receiving anything. What could be the reason behind it?